# Collecting an email address for Text Box in Android?

Tags: java, android

In my new app, i would like to have a text dialog where the user can enter their email address to subscribe to our newsletter and to hear of new updates, features to come.

I am already familiar with using Text dialogs in android.

My question is, when the user hits submit, i would like for the users information entered to be sent to my website or maybe written to a file on my website.

OR is there a way i can have it sent to my email some how? If i could some how add them to a spreadsheet that would also be nice.

At this point i am open to any option that would work and not to difficult to implement.

I dont own a server, but i do have a website with storage space etc through GoDaddy.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much work you want to do, and how much security you want.

If you go with the email option, your application will need a valid email address, password, and server to send email from. This means you will need to embed those variables within your application, and it could be abused.

If you want the address to be written on a file on your website, you will have to allow FTP access within your application, which is another security concern and will increase the amount of code your application needs to work.

The best solution for this scenario would be to have a servlet running on your webserver that can securely communicate with a database. Your Android application can call an HTTP POST message to your servlet containing the user's email address, and the servlet can then save it to a database, which you can pull a spreadsheet from.

This will be the fastest and most secure way of accomplishing what you're wanting.